# bioMart Package error : Request to BioMart web service failed

Tags: r

I am trying to connect list the datasets in bioMart package using

```
listMarts()
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
Request to BioMart web service failed. Verify if you are still connected to the internet.  Alternatively the BioMart web service is temporarily down.  Check http://www.biomart.org and verify if this website is available.
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:
```

Anything wrong I am doing. I tried searching different solutions posted on various forums but I am still getting the same error.